# Formula for creating unique id for group of numbers in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table like this:-
[image]

Here in users column, I have thousand of user's numbers. For each user's group, say for example, all the same user number [like 101 in the table] should be assigned with unique index starting from 1. 
Anyone have idea?

Comment: Are values always in ascending order? Are they all numeric or may contain other characters?

Comment: No there will not be any order, and there will be only numbers

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you want but the pattern you show under `INDEX` may be obtained from that under `USER` with a formula like:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B2)=1,1+MAX(C$1:C1),"")
```

in C2 and copied down to suit.